# Replace the current row with the previous row value based on a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

I want to replace the current row with the previous row based on the hour of the day. I have a data frame with four columns namely date, hour, period (specifying whether night/day) and value. The column 'value' is binary containing the data with either 0 or 1. I specified the hours from 22:00h to 05:00h as sleeping time and the hours from 06:00h to 21:00h as the daytime. Now, if in the nighttime (22:00h to 05:00h), if 1 is detected in the 'value' column in any of the hours between 22:00h and 05:00h, I want to change all the night hours of the particular date to 1. If '0' is detected in all the night hours of the specific date, I want to maintain the value column as '0'. Similar to the dataset attached, I have 'n' number of rows and I want to repeat the same condition to all the dates.

Example of the dataset

[image]

Desired output

[image]

I tried 'na.locf', 'replace' functions in R. But I am not successful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a Minimal reproducible example. See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to analyze if you create a helper column that references the "functional" date that the period ends on, e.g. by adding a day if it's the 10pm or 11pm hour. Then it's straightforward to change the Night values to use the max for that night, so all 1's if any one hour has a 1.

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  mutate(Date_ends_on = Date + if_else(Hour >= 22, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Date_ends_on, Period) %>%
  mutate(New_Value = if_else(Period == "Night", max(Value), Value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would filter out just your "Night" rows and summarise them by the max value and then join that back onto your original data set

```
library(tidyverse)

NIGHT_SUMMARY <- DATA %>%  
  filter(Period=="Night") %>% 
  group_by(Date, Period) %>% 
  summarise(New_Value=max(Value))


NEW_DATA_FRAME <- DATA %>% 
  left_join(NIGHT_SUMMARY, by=c("Date", "Period"))
```

Comment: Thanks, Bevan. I tried the suggested method. But the maximum value is returned as '1' even it is '0'.

Comment: I think because each date has two night periods.  The answer above sorts that out with the Date_ends_on field, use that one

Comment: Certainly. Thanks again